# Laravel - Best strategy to model tables relations

Tags: database, laravel, database-design, eloquent, relation

I have the following issue.

I am trying to find out what is the best way to organize a relationship beetwen Users-Roles-Stores-Schools.

A User can have multiple Roles attached to a Store or to a School, so one can create the realtion :

"User [testuser@email.com] is [root] for school [HighSchool1]"

and also

"User [testuser@email.com] is [user] for store [Store1]"

So a user can have multiple roles, but that roles is attached to a School OR a Store

at begining I was about to do this ...

```
    User
    -id
    -name
    -email
    -password

```
Roles
-id
-name

Roles_user
-id
-rol_id
-user_id
-school_id           //whatch this
-store_id             //whatch this

School
-id
-name

Store
-id
-name
```

The problem is, that in the future, the  system could also handle supermarkets ... and I would have change my roles_user table to attach new columns for that.

How can I achieve this .... using of corse Eloquent and Relationships?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations

Comment: I have read the documentation.  but how can I Access the school/store. ... from a user instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you want to achieve. I will suggest you `business_type` and `business_id` for example

```
Roles_user
-id
-rol_id
-user_id
-business_type           //whatch this
-business_id             //whatch this
```

Business_type could take values such as school, store, supermarket, hotels, and so on, or their ids from a table of registered businesses.

It all depends on what you want to achieve. I hope it helps

Comment: I though about plymorphic relationships. but I dont know how to retrieve the school/store of a user .... from a user instance

Comment: When a user logs in, identify the business. Then select from roles_user where user_id and business_type and business_id. I am commenting based on my answer

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, event hough I though about using plain SQL to retrieve the roles of a user with this model ... I was trying to avoid it. but the asnwer is correct in terms of what and how it should be done.